# How to create a file from command line without redirect or external utils?

Tags: windows, shell, command-line, windows-7

The typical solution (`echo.>filename`) is not acceptable in my scenario (escaping issues). Any other options?

Comment: Explain your escaping issues - there may be a solution

Comment: Can help: http://superuser.com/questions/10426/windows-equivalent-of-the-linux-command-touch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
copy NUL test.txt /Y
```

/Y           Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an
               existing destination file.

Answer (score 0):

Use `touch` command

```
$ touch newfile.txt
$ ls newfile.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 myuser mygroup          0 Dec 15 15:56 newfile.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

```
type nul > "filename here.txt"
```